# Swift Xcode7 and NSObject

Tags: xcode, swift

i'am creating a **sign up and login** app
Here's an inline link to [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbnzve78Tq0) at 28:55

```
class SignUp: NSObject {
    var Nombre: String?
}
```

I have a trouble with a tutorial, i wrote NS.. and nothing appears so it makes an error.

I created a Swift class from ios source.

thanks guys

Comment: you have an error on NSObject? did you import Foundation?

Comment: hi, yes i have an error on NSObject, i didn't import foundation because in the tutorial the guy delete the line

Answer (score 0):

You should put 'import Foundation' and it will work fine